# Вызов перегруженного оператора в методе класса

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов

уважаемые Гуру.

Подскажите, как вызвать перегруженный оператор в методе класса.

Например:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class sc
{
public:
  void operator>>(std::string& receiver)
  {
      receiver.clear();
      receiver = "test";
  }
  void operator>>(std::vector<std::string>& receiver)
  {
      receiver.clear();
      std::string buffer;
      for(auto i{ 0U }; i < 5; ++i)
      {
        this >> buffer; // Здесь хочу вызвать void operator>>(std::string& receiver)
        receiver.push_back(buffer);
      }
  }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> rec;
    sc sc1;
    
    sc1 >> rec;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В определении оператора так:

```
*this >> buffer; // Здесь хочу вызвать void operator>>(std::string& receiver)
```

Ну, или так:

```
this->operator>>(buffer); // Здесь хочу вызвать void operator>>(std::string& receiver)
```

А при вызове —

```
sc1 >> rec;
```

Comment: Логично )) Благодарю за ответ!